# Jenkins - monitor external cron jobs

Tags: cron, jenkins, monitoring, external, jobs

I want to receive notifications on fail of cron job on external server. I also want to be notified when it didn't run at all.

I could do it by this:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs
but it wouldn't report if cron did not run, ex. server went down.

Is there a way to do this without moving jobs to Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try http://www.pushmon.com. It's monitoring for cron jobs. All you have to do is create a PushMon URL and call that URL every time your job runs successfully. If the URL doesn't get called because your job failed or the server is down, PushMon will notice the missing call and will notify you of the problem.

Note I'm associated with PushMon.